# Modifying models to create an association, what is the right way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Say I have two models of an existing Rails 3 application that I want to create an association for:

```
User
AccountType
```

I want to create an association such that I can do:

```
User.account_type
AccountType.users
```

So a user has a single account_type, and a account type has 0 or many users.

At the db level, the user will have a account_type_id and the AccountType table will not have any association related columns for User.

1. So my first step would be to write a test right?  So in both of my user_spec.rb and account_type_spec.rb I should create a simple test to see if it has the proxy class .account_type an account_type.users exist right? anything else?
2. Modify the User.rb model and add belongs_to :AccountType, and in AccountType.rb add a has_many right?
3. Create a migration script, do I just add account_type_id or do I use a special way to reference the AccountType?

Comment: IMO testing to see if the methods exist is unit-testing Rails itself. Tests that use the methods added by the associations will fail if you didn't add the associations already.

Comment: 1- Looks about right 2- Yes you are correct 3- yep just add the account_type_id

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You want something like: `AccountType.users` or `account_type.users`? Since, you said you're establishing  association for an `AccountType` **object** to have many **users** of `User` model then, you need `account_type_id` column in `users` table. And You have to write a method `users` of `AccountType` model if you want to achieve something like: `AccountType.users`. Are you sure what you want out of relationships? Check this link for a better understanding of associations in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding testing: i'd agree with Dave Newton's comment that you should test whatever behaviour you intend to create with this association (so write tests for the ability to create an association, to look up a user or account by this association, etc) but that testing for the existence of the methods as you describe is maybe going farther than necessary.

Your steps 2 and 3 look right to me.

```
rails g migration add_account_type_id_to_users account_type_id:integer
```

should generate the migration you need.